# How to draw a line by the mouse move with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I want to draw a line on a canvas in a wpf by the mouse move. Beginning from a specific shape and having the left mouse button pressed I want to draw a line precisely where the mouse moves. To this end, I have added three event handlers described detailed in the following lines of code:

```
private void output_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(parentCanvas.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
        isMouseDragging = true;
      /*    rectCanvas.MouseLeftButtonDown -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown);
        rectCanvas.MouseLeftButtonUp -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp);
        rectCanvas.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(Canvas_MouseMove);  */

->       parentCanvas.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(output_MouseMove);


    }


  private void output_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDragging = false;

    }

    private void output_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMouseDragging && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            connection_Line = new Polyline();
            connection_Line.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.SlateGray;
            connection_Line.StrokeThickness = 2;
            connection_Line.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;
   ->       var point = e.GetPosition();
            PointCollection myPointCollection = new PointCollection();
            myPointCollection.Add(point);
            connection_Line.Points = myPointCollection;
            parentCanvas.Children.Add(connection_Line);


        }
    }
```

1)  First question is what to add as parameter in the method e.GetPosition() included in the last method, so as to have always the current point where the mouse lies.

2)  Second is if it is reasonable to add an event handler on the parentcanvas to handle the mouse move (in output_MouseLeftButtonDown) or should it be added in a different way (not on the parentCanvas)?

3)  Last, if the whole functionality is expected to work properly or is there a better way to draw a line by the mouse move?

Comment: Ok guys, the first part’ s answer possibly is : var point = new Point(Mouse.GetPosition(parentCanvas).X, Mouse.GetPosition(parentCanvas).Y) Any hint for the second? Where should I assign the MouseMove event handler?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a line that is drawn nearly similar as yours. The only difference is that my line is defined in the xaml view and is part of a special usercontrol derived from a canvas.
To your questions:

1.) the parameter in getPosition is the InputElement which relates to the position you want to find out. As the drawing is taking place on your parentcanvas use this.

2.) as mentioned above parent canvas is your root element so best would be to attach your mouseHandler to the parentCanvas MouseMove

3.) I wouldn't create a new line each time when the mouse moves. Rather use a Line (or Polyline in your case) as a private member or use one defined in XAML and just change its Geometry via the Data Property.
e.g.

```
<Path x:Name="path" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Data="{Binding PathGeometry}">
```

HTH